# I am buidling node.js bindings in C++ should .gitignore the *.gypi files

Tags: c++, node.js, git, node-gyp

I have the following node.js project:

```
.
├── auto.gypi
├── autogypi.json
├── auto-top.gypi
├── binding.gyp
├── build
│------ <Where node-gyp builds>   
├── cpp
│   ├── example.cpp
│   └── example.h
├── index.js
├── node_modules 
|----- <dependencies>
├── package.json
├── package-lock.json
└── structure.txt

305 directories, 1299 files
```

And I `.gitignore` the following files commonly used in node.js project:

```
node_modules
build
```

Bus as you can notice there are some `*.gypi` files. These kind of files are they offer any use if `git add`ed into my project or they should be `.gitignore`d?

Answer (score 0):

If you open one of them you will notice the following comments on the head of it:

```
# Automatically generated file. Edits will be lost.
# Based on: autogypi.json
```

So as you also can unserstand that means 2 things:

- As long as you have the `autogypi.json` file these files can be generated.
- The `autogypi.json` file needs to be watched for changed on your project's version control (aka `git add` them.) program.

Hence, you should `git ingore` both of the `auto.gypi` and the `auto-top.gypi` files via the following entry inti the `.gitignore` file:

```
*.gypi
```